# Compare elements in a list? (Python)

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, list-comparison

I'm working with a couple of filenames in a list where I have already selected files ending in txt to do some processing:

```
my_files = ['my_doc_raw.txt', 'my_doc_transformed.txt', 'some_other_doc.txt', 'requirements.txt']
```

In this case, only one file out of `my_doc_raw.txt` or `my_doc_transformed.txt` needs to go through downstream processing but not both. What is the best approach to ensure I only keep one? I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this filtering with removing both files.

Note that I have a script to determine the datatype of the items in the list. For example:

```
[ data_type(i) for i in my_files ] 

#result
["my_doc", "my_doc", "other_doc", "requirements"]
```

so this gets me a little closer considering that now I have duplicate `my_doc` but I'm not sure where to go from there or to take some other approach. Any tips?

Comment: Create a list from a set so that there are no duplicates.

Comment: What is your exact criterion for deciding that `my_doc_raw.txt` and `my_doc_transformed.txt` should be treated as one ? Do you want to select one file at random ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a clear and proven way of normalizing your filenames (like your `data_type()` function, then all you have to do is keep a list that stores every type you have processed.

Here is a my implementation:

```
my_files = ['my_doc_raw.txt', 'my_doc_transformed.txt', 'some_other_doc.txt', 'requirements.txt']

completed = []

for file in my_files:
    file_type = data_type(file)

    if file_type not in completed:
        #Add type to completed so we don't do it again
        completed.append(file_type)
        upstream_process(file)  #Placeholder for whatever processing you want to do
```

All it does is check if the data type is in our list. If not, then it adds it to the list and does processing. This prevents any data type from being run twice.